# warning"'UIKit bug: Can't have a background image for wantsAdaptiveBackdrop'" in Xcode

Tags: xcode5

My app was working fine in Xcode 4.6 but after updating xcode to xcode5 i am getting warning "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIKit bug: Can't have a background image for wantsAdaptiveBackdrop'".How can i solve this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Xcode 5 which is still under NDA. At this stage discussion on these topics should be done in Apple forums.